# In a puzzle game, how to make the movable tile's hover to be red, and other tiles to keep original?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the part of our code to move tile,what should I do to make the hover to be red?

```
function moveTile(identity) {
var emptyId = findEmptySpace();
if (isEmptyNeighbor(identity)) {
    document.getElementById(identity).id = emptyId;
    document.getElementById(emptyId).onclick = (function (identity) {
        return function () {
            moveTile(identity);
        };
    }(emptyId));
}
```

}

Comment: You will want to use on hover with a specific class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class on the particular tile (then remove it when done). Let's call that class `active`

Declare the class like this

```
.active:hover {
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: .byEmpty:hover { 
    border-color: red;
    color: red;
}
I made a class like this in my css file. But I didnt know how to use it.

Comment: Assuming you have an element you can add a class like this ``element.classList.add('active')``

Comment: can you get the element of the movable tile?

Comment: I made a function to get the movable tiles. So I could use the code You mentioned above to do it?

Comment: ok, and when they are not movable anymore you can remove the class like this ``element.classList.remove('active')``

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I add this    identity.classList.add("byEmpty"); after the  document.getElementById(identity).id = emptyId;, am I adding to a wrong place? Really appreciate it.

Comment: you should add it on the element not the id ``document.getElementById(identity).classList.add('byEmpty')``